# Why some emoji doesn't display well on my Mac?

Tags: emoji

My Mac:
[image]
And I find some emoji doesn't display well on my Mac. Check out that [Link](https://getemoji.com/#symbols):
[image]

Comment: New emoji are added every year.  In order to see all of them, you have to update your OS to the latest version.

Comment: @TomGewecke ...or just copy the font file from a High Sierra installation ;) You may not be able to use them in Messages and such, but at least you would be able to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emoji are a true type font in...

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/System/Library/Fonts/Apple Color Emoji.ttc
```

Sierra comes with version 12.0d19e1, which doesn't include the newest emoji (the ones that are displayed as square in your screenshot), unlike High Sierra, which shows the font as version 13.2d1e1 and can display those newer emoji.

You can use "Font Book.app" in the /Applications folder to preview the font.